# What is the purpose of creating large-scale advertisements to work in a certain industry?

Tags: job-search, recruitment

I've been seeing a lot of advertisements lately that are solely marketing the **Chartered Professional Accountant** career, but don't understand how this would generate a return for the organization running the campaign.

I understand where the benefits are being realized when a company creates an advertisement for a specific job opening (e.g., when software development companies pay Stack Exchange Inc to put ads on careers.stackoverflow.com). However, in this case that I'm questioning, I don't see these ads as any different than a company creating multi-million dollar advertisements that simply say "Become a nurse!" or "Become a quantum physicist!"

In the case of the Chartered Professional Accountant advertisements that I've been seeing, who's paying for these campaigns, and how are they **financially** benefiting from it?

Comment: The UK certainly does/did have ads for things like "become a teacher" and "become a nurse", although these are paid for by the national government who don't necessarily have a direct financial interest.

Comment: Could it be that the advertiser is selling training/qualification/exam/certification ?

Answer (score 2):

Likely the local or national association/union of chartered accountants/nurses/widget flippers is paying for it.  Keeping the profession alive keeps annual dues coming in for them.

The next natural question here is how does this keep the profession alive?  It seems to me the benefit would be two fold.  One would be drawing fresh blood in.  Some trades/professions are not getting enough new blood in to replace those who are retiring.  Supply and demand will balance out eventually however necessity is the mother of invention.  The second benefit is that a labour shortage in a field can force companies to learn to get by without previous staffing levels from chartered accountants/nurses/widget flippers.  Allowing companies this opportunity is very bad for the profession in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I can broadly see two types of companies/organizations doing these campaigns. So, I would explain how they get benefitted from these, and how the advertising actually work:

1. **Coaching(and bootcamp) institutes:** This is obviously the first category which comes to our mind. And they get direct client(or students should be the right term) from the advertisements. They may directly advertise or hire consultants who do the advertising on their behalf.
2. **Growth Hack of companies:** Yes, this is indeed a growth hack. Let me explain you how it works. If the company is a customer service company, then they have to post relevant blog posts for attracting relevant and organic traffic to their site. "**Become a better customer advocate**" or "**30 signs of a wonderful customer service agent**" might be some. And they can advertise the blog posts through some sites. So, here they pay for those ads financially, and they get organic traffic in return. So, both the company and the advertising site are happy.